# How to print JSON data with map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, firebase-realtime-database

That the data in firebase

```
ref = db.reference('/home1')
ref.set({
'slider':
[ 
  {"id" : "1" ,"name":"first","url":"images/gateaux/2D3A3227.jpg"},
  {"id" : "2" ,"name":"second","url":"images/gateaux/pas/2D3A3470.jpg"},
  {"id" : "3" ,"name":"third","url":"images/anniv/deux/2D3A3497.jpg"},
  {"id" : "4" ,"name":"four","url":"images/anniv/2D3A3106.jpg"},
  {"id" : "5" ,"name":"five","url":"images/anniv/2D3A3365.jpg"},
  {"id" : "6" ,"name":"six","url":"images/gateaux/2D3A5245.jpg"}
]
})
```

And my code in react, i try to print the data from firebase, when i print just "product" i receive        all the data, when i print "product.id" i receive slider and when i prind "product.name" i receive     undefined and i want to receive the name like "first" same for url.I need help please

```
export default function Patiss() {
const [home1, sethome1] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
  const usersRef = ref(database,'home1')
  get(usersRef).then((snapshot) => {
    if(snapshot.exists()){
      const userArray = Object.entries(snapshot.val()).map(([id,data])=>({
         id,
        ...data,
      }));
      sethome1(userArray);
     // console.log(userArray)
    }else{
      console.log('no data available');
    }
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.error(error);
});
},[]);
const navigate = useNavigate()
const Keti = () =>{
  navigate("/")
}
return (
  // <div >
    <div className=" mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 py-2  ">
      <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1">
      {/* {home1.length > 0 && home1.map((product, index) => { */}
      {home1.map((product, index) => {
          //  console.log(`${product.name}`); // Should now log the name correctly
           console.log(product); 
           console.log(product.id); 
           console.log(product.name); 
              return (
                <div key={index} className="productDisplay"
                  onClick={() => {
                    navigate(`/home1/${product.id}`);
                  }}
                >
            </div>
        );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
)}

console.log(product) -> all the data print, json
console.log(product.id) -> slider 
console.log(product.name) -> undefined
```

Comment: what value you have in `home1`. could you please add that

Comment: Looks like you actually want to save your data as an array. Why are you storing an object with a `slider` property that contains your array?

Comment: If you don't want to change the storage, just use `sethome1(snapshot.val().slider))`.  Again though, it's really unclear why you have the data structure you do

Comment: How do you recommend changing the storage?

Comment: you want to display Json in View ?

Comment: just the data like "first"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `ref.set`, you're writing the values under a key `"slider"` and that is missing in your code that reads the data back.

```
const usersRef = ref(database,'home1/slider') // 
get(usersRef).then((snapshot) => {
  ...
```

Comment: @ Frank. maybe you know why i receive the address of url in the localhost and not the image itself?